# Image not draping over DEM in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I saw [Images not draping onto DEM in ArcScene?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/246725/115) but it is different from my issue. I have an image with projection:

NAD_1983_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet.

I have a DEM and set the base height to itself and I am getting a good DEM representation of the terrain. I added the image and set the base height to the DEM and it doesn't drape on top of DEM, it appears to be below DEM surface.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happened to me as well with ArcScene, you simply have to set a vertical offset to your draped image.
After having set the base height (the DEM layer) for your image, right click the image layer and set a constant offset to it.

Comment: Thanks, I set a vertical offset of 1.03 and that worked. Both data sets are have units of US foot, I'm wondering why I had to set a vertical offset for them to line up if they are in same units?